# Cannot get input type search to work with OnsenUI / AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm trying to use an input type search like this:

```html
<input type="search" ng-model="main.toSearch" placeholder="Search..." class="search-input" onsearch="main.doSearch()"></input>
```

main is my controller (I'm declaring it as "MainController as main "). The binding to main.toSearch works fine, but main.doSearch never gets called. If I put some random javascript it gets called, but it seems to not find main.

Can anyone please explain what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onsearch="main.doSearch()"` doesn't look right. You need to use angular directives to call methods attached to your scope.

Do you have a `$scope.main.doSearch()` method? If you want to call the method when the user presses the Enter key you can put it in a `<form>` element and use the `ngSubmit` directive:

```
<form ng-submit="main.doSearch()">
  <input type="search" ng-model="main.toSearch" placeholder="Search..." class="search-input"></input>
</form>
```

For `onsearch` to work, `main` must be a global object which you should avoid.

Please look at this pen for an example:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/ByyjKe

Comment: I came here to post that I figured it out, wrapping the input in a form, but you beat me to it! Thanks!